# How does NSActor work and what is NSActor used for?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Sorry if this is a newbish question but, can some one tell me in an easy way what the use of NSActor is for and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a private class used internally by Apple.  I have no idea what it does, but I would guess it's an implementation of the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) for concurrency.  If you don't know what it does, chances are you have no reason to use it, although it might be fun to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such class listed in the documentation.  Where did you see it, and why do you think you need it?

Comment: I found it here: http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/tree/master/ActorKit/ I found it while looking at KennyTM's profile on SO and saw his website. There really isn't any need for it I'm just curious to know.

Comment: @thyrgle if it's just for curiosity, then cool.  but FYI, if you try to use private api in an app, it will be rejected by Apple before a human ever looks at it (although I'm sure you're aware of this). :)